# Trouble aligning partial header in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want the "n" to be centered over the 50? How can I achieve this?

```
  \begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Condition Numbers} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{n} \\
    Correlation Structure    & 30 & 50 & 100 \\
    \hline
    Gnat                     & per gram    & 13.65     & 100    \\
                             & each        & 0.01      & 100  \\ 
    Gnu                      & stuffed     & 92.50      & 100 \\
    Emu                      & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
    Armadillo                & frozen      & 8.99       & 100\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{4}{c}{Condition Numbers} \\
    & & n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply place the "n" in the third column. I'd suggest you to use the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and [`booktab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktab) packages (notice the alignment for the third column):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcSc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Condition Numbers} \\
    & & {n} \\
    Correlation Structure    & 30 & {50} & 100 \\
    \midrule
    Gnat                     & per gram    & 13.65     & 100    \\
                             & each        & 0.01      & 100  \\ 
    Gnu                      & stuffed     & 92.50      & 100 \\
    Emu                      & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
    Armadillo                & frozen      & 8.99       & 100\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`50` is in a centered column, thus all you need is to put `n` into the same column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Condition Numbers} \\
    && n \\
    Correlation Structure    & 30 & 50 & 100 \\
    \hline
    Gnat                     & per gram    & 13.65     & 100    \\
                             & each        & 0.01      & 100  \\
    Gnu                      & stuffed     & 92.50      & 100 \\
    Emu                      & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
    Armadillo                & frozen      & 8.99       & 100\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]